# Caps Lock Key Mappings on 17.10

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to remap my caps lock key to function as escape when hit on its own and control when held along with another key as shown below:

```
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
```

This worked well until I updated to 17.10. Now, when I hit Caps Lock, it does seem to function as an escape key, but rather than override the default behavior it *also* toggles the caps lock. Also, using the key as a control modifier does not seem to work.

Any ideas what might be causing these issues?